# Does jxbrowser support swipe and scrolling of a webpage via touchscreen?

Tags: jxbrowser

Does jxbrowser support swipe and scrolling of a webpage via touchscreen on Windows XP system? I found topic:
https://groups.google.com/a/teamdev.com/forum/#!topic/jxbrowser-forum/T4fH_7Z8H7c
but as I see it's implemented only for Windows 8.x, am I right? 
On our system it works with touch but the behavior is simulate of handling with mouse. I mean if I touch on arrow in the scrollbar it will scroll but I can not scroll swiping in the middle of page. We use version 6.5.
Is it possible to configure it somehow so it will work on Windows XP or this functionality is not implemented?

Regards,
Pavlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know swipe gestures were introduced in Windows 8. Touch gestures in Chromium engine are implemented using Windows 8 SDK, so they will not work on Windows XP at all. All touch events are simulated as mouse events on Windows XP, but if we are talking about gestures, then I don't think that Windows XP "knows" how to extract gesture from a set of mouse events (especially if we are talking about multi touch). I recommend that you first check how Google Chrome works on Windows XP with touch screen. If Google Chrome doesn't work in such environment, then JxBrowser will not work in the same environment as well.